# Drop Row with a condition 'method' object is not subscriptable in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove a few 1000 rows because they belong to the month of October. I have a column by the name 'Month'.

```
import pandas as pd
#change the file path
file_path = r'Dboard.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name = 'rawdump', index_col=0)

#Created a date constant filter
sep_filter = df['Month'] == 9
aug_filter = df['Month'] == 8


#Drop Oct Rows
df1 = df.drop[df['Month'] == 10]
```

[ERROR] is

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        11 
>        12 #Drop Oct Rows
>   ---> 13 df1 = df.drop[mea_df['Month'] == 10]
>        14 
>        15

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Here is an example of my raw data (Note there are 30 columns and more than 200K rows, but I am giving an example)
**Input**

```
Date         Campaign Month Cost  Clicks
01/10/2019    A        10    30    100
01/09/2019    A        10    80    400
01/08/2019    A        10    20    100
01/10/2019    B        10    30    100
01/09/2019    B        10    80    400
01/08/2019    B        10    20    100
01/10/2019    C        10    30    100
01/09/2019    C        10    80    400
01/08/2019    C        10    20    100
```

Here is my desired Output
**Output**

```
Date         Campaign Month Cost  Clicks
01/09/2019    A        10    80    400
01/08/2019    A        10    20    100
01/09/2019    B        10    80    400
01/08/2019    B        10    20    100
01/09/2019    C        10    80    400
01/08/2019    C        10    20    100
```

[NEW ERROR]

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2656             try:
>   -> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Date'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         6 
>         7 #Drop Oct Rows
>   ----> 8 df[df['Date'].dt.month != 10]
>         9 
>        10
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   **getitem**(self, key)    2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:    2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
>   -> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    2928             if is_integer(indexer):    2929                 indexer = [indexer]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2657                 return
>   self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
>   -> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2660
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance) 
>   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: Remove `drop and change `==` to `!=` ` - `df[df['Month'] != 10]`

Comment: there are existing rows inside the excel sheet which i need to remove oct rows from it.

Comment: yes, solution from dupe or from comment not working?

Comment: Its working, but would it remove the existing Month 10 rows. I would need to add new Oct rows. My data refreshes everyday.

Comment: hope now the description of my problem is clear

Comment: So need `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)` and `df[df['Date'].dt.month != 10]` ?

Comment: I have posted a new error

Comment: Use `df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True) and df[df.index.month != 10]`

Comment: got this working. Thanks. But after exporting the excel file, my date is coming as 2019-09-01 00:00:00. I don't know why. I am trying to remove the time and also change the date to correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#add parse_dates for `DatetimeIndex`
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name = 'rawdump', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

#compare months of DatetimeIndex and filter
df1 = df[df.index.month != 10].copy()
#change format of datetimes
df1.index = df1.index.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

#save to file
df1.to_csv(file)
```